# tf.keras.optimizers.Adam and other optimizers with minimization

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I want to use the `tf.contrib.keras` to play around with it. However, there is something I don't understand. The classes from `tf.train` have a function `minimize` that you use for the optimization of your function. However, this `minimize` function does not exists for the classes in `tf.contrib.keras.optimizers`. Let's say we have the following code:

```
# tensorflow
tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
updateModel = trainer.minimize(loss)

# keras wrapper
trainer=tf.contrib.keras.optimizers.Adam()
updateModel = trainer.minimize(loss) # ERROR because minimize function does not exists
```

The `keras` wrapper wont work because there is no `minimize` function. I'm trying to look for an example or workaround using `tf.keras` with tensorflow, but I don't find anything that helps me with that.

P.S. Here I'm using `tf.contrib.keras.optimizers.Adam` as a dummy example, but I would like to use other optimizers from the same package.

Answer (score 2):

This caused because of differences between `keras` and `tensorflow` APIs. In `keras` optimizer is a function provided during model compilation which is used for a gradient descent optimization:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', ...)
model.fit(..) <- optimiziation performed using Adam algorithm
```

In `tensorflow` - you may use it in a custom manner as you presented.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I'm looking for that custom manner to optimize `keras` through `tensorflow`. I might be wrong, but I think that's the purpose of having the subpackage.

Comment: I agree with @Marcin, Keras was meant to be used "wrapping" Tensorflow inside it. You use it as a higher level API and leave the dirty work to the backstage. The idea is exactly: `create a keras model -> compile the model with an optimizer -> fit/train the model`

Comment: Keras handles tensorflow, not the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion is caused by the fact that `tf.contrib.keras` API is *not exactly* tensorflow and isn't meant to be used like core tensorflow<sup>1</sup>.

If you look at the source code, the classes from `tf.contrib.keras.optimizers` are almost identical to ones from `keras.optimizers`. E.g., the first [`Optimizer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/optimizers.py#L67) and the second [`Optimizer`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L49), the first [`SGD`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/optimizers.py#L151) and the second [`SGD`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L49), and so on. Keras is being gradually incorporated in tensorflow, but right now it's more like another project bundled together with tensorflow and can't be easily used with the arbitrary tensorflow graph. Instead, *keras* optimizers should be used with *keras* layers.

So you can either stick to the all-tensorflow API and use [`tf.train.AdamOptimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer) (like you do right now) or to all-keras API and use `Adam` (see Marcin's answer). I don't see any value in mixing the two.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> At least in TF 1.x. Keras might be integrated more with TF in the future versions.</sup>